# CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() throws an unexpected exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, semaphore

Can anyone help and determine if this is my error or the unlikely .Net bug?

The code below shows a Main() routine starting 10 tasks, using the DoNothing() method as the underlying method and a SemphoreSlim that will allow 3 tasks to run simultaneously.
Then the Main() waits for a duration of time:

```
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

After the wait we cancel all tasks:

```
cancel.Cancel();
```

At which point I expected the .ContinueWith(..) to take over:

```
doNothingTasks.Add(
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doNng.DoNothing(canToken), canToken)
    .ContinueWith(_ => { Console.WriteLine(..);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled)
```

Instead I get an exception on the following line in the DoNothing() routine:

[image: Exception User-Unhandled]

This is unexpected.

Output at exception is:
[image: Output at exception]

Can anyone explain???

Complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Broker = new SemaphoreSlim(3);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doNothingTasks = new List<Task>();
            using (var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                var canToken = cancel.Token;

                for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                {
                    var doNng = new TestCancellationToken(i);
                    doNothingTasks.Add(
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                            doNng.DoNothing(canToken), canToken)
                        .ContinueWith(_ => { Console.WriteLine(
                            $"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.ffff}.  " +
                            $"{new string('.', 25)} {doNng.Name} " +
                            $"WAS CANCELLED {new string('.', 10)}");
                        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled)
                );
            }

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            cancel.Cancel();

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(doNothingTasks.ToArray());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                var fae = ae.Flatten();
                foreach (var ex in fae.InnerExceptions)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.ffff}.  " +
                        $"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class TestCancellationToken
    {
        private readonly Random _rnd;
        public int Name { get; }

        public TestCancellationToken(int inx)
        {
            _rnd = new Random(inx);
            Name = inx;
        }

        public void DoNothing(CancellationToken canToken)
        {
            for (var i = 0; ; ++i)
            {
                if (canToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    canToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                Broker.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.ffff}.  " +
                    $"Test {Name} round: {i}, aquire time");
                var sleepPeriod = _rnd.Next(750) + 50;

                Thread.Sleep(sleepPeriod);
                Broker.Release();
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.ffff}.  " +
                    $"Test {Name} round: {i}, release time: {sleepPeriod}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why is that unexpected? You need to catch the exception so you can gracefully exit the task and then the continue with will run. `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` will throw an exception, it even says that in the method name...

Comment: The output looks fine to me. If the problem is just that when running in the debugger, the debugger pauses, that's just due to your exception settings. What difference do you expect in your output? (It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with the non-cancellation part of the code.)

Comment: Side note: What's the point of checking for cancellation before using the ThrowIf... api?

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I appreciate your help.